# Visual Studio Code No colors or code recommendations

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

When coding in VSC, no recommendations or color coordinations appear.

They were on before, and I can't seem to figure out the problem. I tried restarting, and with other languages, both appear, but with HTML and CSS they don't. I know HTML isn't actually a language, and so I downloaded the Live Server extension to run my code.

This is more of a small annoyance than anything else, but I would like it solved as I'm pretty new and I don't know all of the text options and colors there are.

[image: VSC Unstyled Text]

Comment: fullscreen please

Answer (score 3):

firstly you will need to save the file out in the correct format extension (e.g: save index as index.html / style as style.css ) within your folders, VSC should pickup the language and syntax you are using. If this still doesn't work, on the far bottom right panel of VSC you can select the language you are using.

By default, new documents are displayed as plain text until they are changed or saved out in the correct format.

[image: VSC Fix]